# ajax responsetext blank/empty in chrome works fine in IE

Tags: ajax, responsetext

receiving status = 200 statustext = OK in chrome console
alert "onSuccess" working in IE but not in CHROME

```
new Ajax.Request("downstocking_apply_async.do", {
                onSuccess : function(transport) {
                alert("onSuccess");
                if (!isHangingRequest()){ 
                    initUpdateScanArea(transport.responseText);
                }else{
                    doSuspend();

                }},
                onFailure : function(transport) {
                if (!isHangingRequest()){ 
                    document.downstockingForm.action = "downstocking_apply_async.do?" + param;
                    document.downstockingForm.submit();
                }else{
                    doSuspend();

                } 
             },
             parameters : param,
             asynchronous : "true"
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

found the solution...custom js library that was imported is creating confusion with prototype js thanks!